# ReactJS Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: json, reactjs

I have read a few top posts from searching and nothing so far quite fits my scenario. Even VSCode was able to recognize that function, but somehow React couldn't?

My jsx: (EDIT: Thanks to @Dannis Vash, seems like it's the sorting algorithm which I originally didn't include here that broke the code)

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import glossaryItems from '../../data/glossary-items.json';

function Glossary(){

    const [items, setItems] = useState(glossaryItems);

    /* Algorithm that's suspected of breaking the code */
    const sortItems = () =>{
        let sortedItems = [...items.glossaryItems].sort((item1, item2) => {
            if(item1.itemName < item2.itemName){
                return -1;
            }
            if(item1.itemName > item2.itemName){
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        });

        setItems(sortedItems);
    }

    /* Sorts the items on component render */
    useEffect(()=>{sortItems()},[]);

    const sortedItems = items;
    console.log(sortedItems); // This does log the entire array
    const glossary = sortedItems.glossaryItems.map((item) =>{
        return(
            {item.name}
        );
    });

    return(
        <div>
            <div className="glossary-body">
                {glossary}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Glossary;
```

My json:

```
{
    "glossaryItems":[
        {
            "itemName": "Item 1",
            "to": "www.google.com"
        },
        {
            "itemName": "Item 2",
            "to": "github.com"
        },
        {
            "itemName": "Item 3",
            "to": "127.0.0.1"
        }
    ]
}
```

And it tells me that it can't read map of type undefined, which seems weird to me because when I hovered over map in VSCode, it actually showed the correct function. Any insights? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your item key is `itemName` and not `name`:

```
// not item.name
const glossary = items.glossaryItems.map(item => item.itemName);
```

Also, in `sortItems` you actually removed the `glossaryItems` key:

```
// Is an array of objects
const sortItems = [...items.glossaryItems];

// While you need is an object: { glossaryItems: [...] }
```

Therefore you need to add it back or not to use it:

```
setItems({ glossaryItems: sortedItems });
const glossary = items.glossaryItems?.map(item => item.itemName);

// Optionioal chaining.
setItems(sortedItems);
const glossary = items?.map(item => item.itemName);
```

[image: Edit dazzling-wood-05tdn]

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry - I actually returned more than just the name and was doing so for simplification of the sample code. As of itemName, thanks for pointing that out! It still didn't fix my problem though :(

Comment: Try to re-create the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-dubinsky-7jcr2?file=/index.js:254-267

Comment: Hmmm interesting, seems like putting in my sorting algorithm broke the code https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-tree-iytb2

Comment: Your removed the `glossaryItems` key on destructing. See https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-wood-05tdn?file=/index.js

Comment: Aah, thanks so much! Can you explain more about how the glossaryItems got removed, if you don't mind?